# Do the following properties characterize the set membership?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set $S$, a relation $R \subseteq S \times \mathcal P(S)$ has the following properties: $\forall x \in S, \forall A, B \in  \mathcal P(S)$,

- $(x, \emptyset) \notin R$
- if $x \in A$, then $(x,A) \in R$
- if $(x,A) \in R$ and $\forall y \in A, (y,B) \in R$, then $(x,B) \in R$.

Must $R$ be the set membership? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But it must be the case that $\in$ is a subset of $R$. Consider $R=S\times(\mathcal P(S)\setminus\{\varnothing\})$, and see that it satisfies all three properties.

The key problem is that you only require one direction of a bidirectional condition in your second condition.

Comment: thanks. (1) if I change the second property to be bidirectional, then it is trivially that $R$is the set membership. (2) I saw that such a relation $R$ is called "betweenness" in *Theory_of_Convex Structures* by Van de Vel, but don't quite understand [how it is involved in "convexity structures"](http://books.google.com/books?id=oDUmytVzSPMC&lpg=PA32&ots=va1m3P2nZg&dq=betweenness%22%20in%20Theory_of_Convex%20Structures%20by%20Van%20de%20Vel%2C&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q&f=false). So I wonder if there is more about that

Comment: (1) Indeed. (2) I don't quite know about that.

Comment: Are you able to characterize the set membership as a relation?

Comment: that will be a circular definition, will it?

Comment: Tim, the point is that $\in$ is a primitive relation. This is like trying to characterize equality, another primitive notion. You have to ask, characterize in terms of what? In languages where $\in$ is not primitive it can be done in a non-trivial way, by using its definition from the primitive notions (e.g. if the primitive relation is $\subseteq$, we can define $x\in y\iff\{x\}\subseteq y$).

Comment: In what order do people usually characterize related notions? What notions or languages do they usually assume, an then further define other notions?

Comment: I don't really know how to answer that. Foundationally, the whole point in set theory as a foundation is that you can do with just $\in$ and a few axioms. Outside of set theory, I suppose that one has all sort of things in "the language of mathematics" and they have their "obvious interpretation" which makes them atomic somehow.

Comment: thanks, Asaf. Is it possible to give some properties on  relation $R \subseteq S \times \mathcal P(S)$, so that $R$ is the set membership, allowing using the set membership to describe the properties but in a nontrivial way?

Comment: Tim, I think that if one adds extensionality, then one can prove that. This is just a less-trivial way of stating the missing condition.

Comment: The second property is called "extensiveness" in the book. What is your "extensionality"?

Comment: It's not mine, it's a standard term. The axiom of extensionality is what connects $=$ and $\in$: $$x=y\leftrightarrow\forall z(z\in x\leftrightarrow z\in y)$$ In your case you can add the requirement that $A=B$ if and only if for all $x$, $(x,A)\in R\leftrightarrow (x,B)\in B$.